# How to trigger click event on child component in VueJS unit test?

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, vue.js

I have the following Vue component:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <year-btn @click="incrementYear"
                ref="increment-btn"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
import yearBtn from "@/components/formInputs/yearBtn.vue";

export default {
    components: {
        "year-btn": yearBtn,
    },
    data() {
        return {
            monthAndYear: {
                year: 2000,
            },
        };
    },
    methods: {
        incrementYear() {
            this.monthAndYear.year++;
        },
    },
};
</script>
```

And I have the following Vue unit test.

```
it('test', async () => {
    wrapper = factory();

    wrapper.setData({
        monthAndYear: {
            year: 2020,
        },
    });

    wrapper.find({ ref: "increment-btn" }).trigger("click");
    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    result = wrapper.vm.monthAndYear.year;
    expect(result).toEqual(2021);
});
```

Unfortunately, the above test fails because the click event on the 'year-btn' component fails to be triggered by Vue Test Utils. I know this because, if I replace my template with the following code the test passes.

```
<template>
    <div>
        <div>
            <button @click="incrementYear"
                ref="increment-btn"></button>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

**My question is, how do I trigger a "click" event on a child component (year-btn) that my component is using?**

Below is what the year-btn component looks like:

```
<template>
    <button @click="$emit('click')">
        Click me
    </button>
</template>
```

Comment: @tony19 its at the bottom of my post - all it does is emit a click event when there is a click on the button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems likely that `factory()` is using [`shallowMount`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/shallowMount.html), which stubs its child components. Switch to [`mount`](https://vue-test-utils.vuejs.org/api/mount.html) to ensure the `YearBtn` is actually rendered.

Answer (score 2):

If you add `console.log` to `incrementYear` you will see that ref holds component object not DOM element.

```
    incrementYear() {
      this.monthAndYear.year++;
      console.log(this.$refs['increment-btn'])
    },
```

So try to change this:

```
wrapper.find({ ref: "increment-btn" }).trigger("click");
```

to this:

```
wrapper.find({ ref: "increment-btn" }).$el.trigger("click");
```

Comment: Didn't work unfortunately. I get `TypeError: Cannot read property 'trigger' of undefined` when the test is run.

Comment: Great answer ^^ N.B. Vue is deprecating `wrapper.find` in favour of `wrapper.findComponent` if anyone else stumbles across this.

Comment: @SRack Only for finding components specifically. `wrapper.find` is still applicable for finding DOM elements.